# Which JQuery plug-in to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table in the HTML and the table contents are injected by JavaScript to HTML.

I have plans to change the table to some nice layout using Jquery plugins. The jQuery grid/table mush have property of Fixed header.

Which one would you all suggest?

*[Description: I have a JavaScript that gathers data from few sources and prepares HTML elements and puts that on the HTML as a table. The backend code (i.e. the JavaScript) is quite big and i do not want to modify it. Only minor modification i would like to do, for this purpose i would like to replace the table with any grid. ]*

Comment: Ashwin can you elaborate your query

Comment: @Rahul: I have a JavaScript that gathers data from few sources and prepares HTML elements and puts that on the HTML as a table. The backend code (i.e. the JavaScript) is quite big and i do not want to modify it. Only minor modification i would like to do, for this purpose i would like to replace the table with any grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables is certainly a good choice but can give a bit of overhead on client side, in terms of functionalities and code/images downloaded by the client.

Decide what you want to achieve and choose the minimum.

For example, do you need to style your table only? Do what DataTables does by yourself as explained in

[JQuery Zebra striping](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aZebra_Striping_Made_Easy)

Comment: I want a table with minimum functionalities. I mean, only a table with fixed header, variable column widths.. Other functions like- sorting, exporting, etc.. are already handled in the JavaScript.

Comment: In this case I'd say that the DIY is the best approach. You got code for zebra striping, you can write a custom tooltip/long entry cutter, and some style in one hour. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

may be you are searching for this one...

[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net)

Comment: Can you provide an example? It would be great.

Comment: @Ashwin - I recommend DataTables as well. It has a lot of functionality and pretty good documentation. Check out the examples on the DataTables site - http://www.datatables.net/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/)

You can also pull down data from a database using Ajax with this plugin